# Why wait to eat if it rains on the first night of Sukkot?

Tags: sukkah, sukkot, weather, mishnah-berurah

If it is raining on the first night of Sukkot, [Rema Orach Chayyim 639:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.639.5?lang=bi) writes:

> לילה הראשונה צריך לאכול כזית בסוכה אף אם גשמים יורדין ויקדש בסוכה כדי שיאמר זמן על הסוכה
>
> On the first night, one must eat a *kezayit* [of bread] in the *sukkah*, even if rain is falling. One makes *kiddush* in the *sukkah* in order to recite *shehecheyanu* in the *sukkah*.

[Mishnah Berurah 639:35](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.639.35?lang=bi) quotes opinions that do not allow one to recite the blessing of *leisheiv basukkah* under such circumstances. He therefore advises one to wait to recite *kiddush* (for an hour or two, or possibly even until midnight) because:

> פן יעבור הגשם דאם יעבור יכנס לסוכה ויברך ברכת לישב בסוכה ויאכל ויוצא בזה המ"ע לכו"ע
>
> Maybe the rain will clear, and if it does, he can then go into the *sukkah*, make the blessing of *leisheiv basukkah* and eat and thus fulfill the biblical *mitzvah* according to all opinions.

I don't understand why one needs to wait to eat. Why can't you make *kiddush* in the *sukkah* and simply omit *leisheiv*? Then eat the entire meal in the house (assuming one can obviate issues with *kiddush bimkom seudah*). Then wait as long as you can (perhaps until midnight) for the rain to stop, in which case you  return to the *sukkah*, recite *leisheiv* and eat a *kezayit* of bread. If the rain doesn't stop, then, before you go to sleep, simply eat a *kezayit* of bread in the *sukkah* in the rain, without *leisheiv*.

The advantage of this method is that this doesn't interfere with one's *simchat yom tov* (a concern Mishnah Berurah himself worries about in this very same paragraph.)

One issue I can see with this method is that you are reciting *shehecheyanu* during *kiddush* on the *sukkah* at a time when you may be exempt from the *mitzvah*. However, as Mishnah Berurah points out in his [next paragraph](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.639.36?lang=bi):

> דאפילו אם נימא דפטור אז מסוכה מ"מ יוצא בזה דלא גריע ד"ז מאלו בירך שהחיינו בחול בשעת עשייה בסוכה דיוצא בזה
>
> Even if we say that one was exempt at that time [when he said *shehecheyanu* in the *sukkah* while it was raining on the first night], he has nevertheless fulfilled his obligtion. This is because it is no worse than had he recited *shehecheyanu* before *yom tov* when he built the *sukkah*, in which case one has fulfilled the obligation.

Comment: Sorta similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76915/759 My feeling has been that since the Gemara mentions how to say Leishev with Kiddush, Rishonim assume there's value to saying them together. I don't know what that value is.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's an interesting suggestion to explore. Worth noting in that context is that if it's raining on the second night, MB rules to make kiddush in the house without leisheiv. (Although even there he thinks it's a good idea to wait a bit.)

Comment: probably because not everyone always had enough bread; and/or once people eat bread they feel full and might not want to eat again. Second night could be worried about sefeika d'yoma.

Comment: @JoelK It's interesting that MB has different rules for the 2nd night. I wonder what he says to do if it rained **both** nights.

Comment: I wonder if he feels there's a Bittul Aseh by actively eating bread outside the Sukkah before having eaten the obligatory bread inside. Consider the case of Pesach night: if you don't have enough Matza you can eat Matza at Afikoman and eat Matza Ashira at the beginning of the meal, but maybe eating real Matza without the Mitzva before doing it for the Mitzva (is that possible?) would be Bittul Aseh. For sukkot the parallel solution, since egg challah is generally seen as acceptable for the first night, might be Pat HaBa BeKisnin?

Comment: Another concern could be eating before doing a Mitzva when the time of the Mitzva has come, since accd to some the time to eat in the Sukkah is now

Comment: @DoubleAA It doesn't seem from MB 639:36 that either of the points you raise would be a concern. It sounds like he would be happy for you to make kiddush in the house, eat the whole meal there and then eat a final kebeitzah of bread in the sukkah, were it not for the preference for the shehecheyanu of kiddush to relate to the sukkah as well.

Comment: I hear. It will probably be helpful to track down whatever Acharonim the MB is basing himself on and see their formulations

Comment: The MB himself says that the reason of the ram”a is that he holds that he is not pattur from leishev basukkah (דאף שהוא מצטער מחמת הגשם וכל מצטער פטור מסוכה סבירא ליה להרמ"א כדעת הפוסקים דסוברין דבלילה ראשונה אף מצטער חייב) . So even if it was still raining in the given scenario, it seems to me that he would still have to say leishev basukkah.

Comment: @Loani Rama holds he’s obligated to eat some bread in the sukkah in the rain on the first night. Not to make kiddush there

Comment: @JoelK “ One makes *kiddush* in the *sukkah*”.

Comment: @Loani To avoid reciting shehecheyanu twice. Not because of any intrinsic obligation to say kiddush in the sukkah

Comment: @Joel K, either way, I meant that in the OP’s situation (that if it’s still raining at midnight he should eat in the sukkah without leishev) IMO the ram”a would hold that he would still say leishev, because he holds that we eat bread in the sukkah even in the rain, and his reason (as the MB explains) is that he is still chayav in leishev.

Comment: @Loani I agree. And the MB would still say not to say Leishev because he has a safek.

Comment: @Joel K hence my answer. But the MB may hold that it is better to eat now than to wait any longer, and then the question is, does he now say a b’racha.

Comment: @Loani I'm pretty sure he would say not to say leishev: הכריעו כמה אחרונים דאף דמחוייב לאכול בסוכה מחמת ספק ברכת לישב בסוכה לא יברך דספק ברכות להקל

Comment: @Joel K Possibly. Although he may pasken like the Rama in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The peninei Halacha says (my translation):

> למנהג אשכנז, העומד לאכול שיעור שחייבים לאוכלו בסוכה, מברך על אכילתו 'לישב בסוכה'. לפיכך, המתכוון לאכול פת או מזונות כשיעור יותר מנפח 'ביצה', יחד עם הברכה על האוכל מברך 'לישב בסוכה'. ומי שאינו מתכוון לאכול כשיעור זה במשך כל שהייתו הנוכחית בסוכה, יברך 'לישב בסוכה' גם על טעימה כל שהיא של מזונות או יין או מאכל חשוב אחר. ואף שיש בזה עוד מנהגים, כך ראוי לנהוג.
>
> According to the ashkenazi custom, one who plans to eat an amount that one must eat in the sukkah (ie kebeitza) blesses “leishev besukkah”. Therefore if one plans to eat more than on kebeitza of bread or mezonos, says leishev besukkah in addition to the blessing on the food. But one who doesn’t plan on eating a kebeitza during this whole time in the sukkah, says “leishev besukkah” on even a small taste (is less than a kebeitza, probably less than a kezayis) of mezonos OR WINE or any other important food. And even though there are other traditions, this is the best way to act.

We see from here that one may not drink wine while in the sukkah without saying leishev besukkah, if he’s not planning to eat bread or mezonos before leaving (which is exactly the given case).
Furthermore, the Mishna Berurah prohibits saying Kiddush in the rain, and gives the reason that it is because of the safek of leishev basukkah, which implies that according to the Mishnah Berurah as well, in this case one must say leishev basukkah even on wine according to some opinions, so the safek stands even for wine.

The same is true in the given case if it continues raining: one may not eat a kezayis of bread in the sukkah without saying leishev besukkah (and one may not say leishev besukkah while it’s raining according to some opinions, as mentioned in the question). Therefore the suggested solution doesn’t work, and we have to wait until the rain clears.

Comment: 1) as noted by the Pninei Halakha not everyone holds of this so the question holds for the other opinions 2) does anyone hold you need a leshev basukkah on wine the first night in the rain? The only possible reason to eat in the rain the first night is the opinion that you must have some bread in the Sukkah like you must have Matza the first night of pesach. Nothing about wine or any other food. Everyone would agree you don't need to drink wine in the rain in the Sukkah ever.

Comment: @DoubleAA but since the Mishna Berurah doesn’t allow saying kiddish in the sukkah in the rain because some hold that he can’t say leishev now, it seems logical that the Mishna Berurah holds that one does need to say leishev on wine (at least in this case). Therefore, it seems that there is a mitzva to drink wine in the sukkah.

Comment: Well, that's the OPs question. Is that why the MB doesn't allow Kiddush in the rain first? You've asserted that, but I question it. The OP wasn't sure why the MB doesn't allow saying Kiddush right away in the Sukkah and eating inside before returning later.

Comment: (on the other hand, Misvara you'd expect the Brakha in the case of rain the first night to be said not during Kiddush according to the Rama, but he never says that. hmmm)

Comment: @DoubleAA why else would the MB be Machmir, if not because of the problem of leishev? In fact, we can be Medayek from the MB (if the OP quoted and understood him correctly) that he holds that this problem *is* the reason he is Machmir: “Mishnah Berurah 639:35][2] quotes opinions that do not allow one to recite the blessing of *leisheiv basukkah* under such circumstances. He THEREFORE advises one to wait to recite *kiddush*”. Therefore, meaning because of the safek of leishev.

Comment: @DoubleAA why else would the MB be osser kiddush in the sukkah? Especially since his only reason given is that “the ram”a agrees with the ones who hold that even a mitzta’er is chayav on the first night”. And since he doesn’t allow kiddush, he probably includes kiddush in that chiyuv.

Comment: Continued: and once kiddush is part of the chiyuv, he can’t say kiddush in the sukkah in the rain with leishev, because of those who hold that it is not a mitzva and therefore a b’racha levatalah, and he can’t say kiddush in the sukkah in the rain without leishev, because of those who hold it is a mitzva and he is therefore missing the b’racha (although the second can be overruled because b’rachos lo me’akvin, but lechatchila it’s still better to wait until you can say a b’racha)

Comment: I gave two possible reasons why else in comments on the question. "Why else" isn't a good argument to answer the OP.

Comment: @DoubleAA as I pointed out above, the MB’s reason is because of the safek of leishev, as he himself writes. The MB goes on to say that he must wait to say kiddush, Mashma that he includes kiddush in the safek. This seems perfectly logical to me, especially since it is backed up by the peninei Halacha

Comment: I don't understand what Diyuk you are making in the MB. Can you quote the relevant words and explain what you think he's saying?

Comment: @DoubleAA “וע"כ הכריעו כמה אחרונים דאף דמחוייב לאכול בסוכה מחמת ספק ברכת לישב בסוכה לא יברך דספק ברכות להקל עוד כתבו דראוי להמתין עד חצות הלילה פן יעבור הגשם דאם יעבור יכנס לסוכה ויברך ברכת לישב בסוכה ויאכל ויוצא בזה המ"ע לכו"ע...ואם לא פסקו יעשה אז קידוש בסוכה”

Comment: I don't see how that supports anything you wrote. He doesn't say explicitly why you need to wait for Kiddush and can't do what the OP suggested

Comment: @Double AA one moment my connection is bad. Continued: The reason why we wait, as the MB says, is because of the safek of leishev, so we wait hoping that the rain will stop, so we can eat with leishev according to all the opinions. If it doesn’t stop by midnight, we say kiddush in the sukkah. Seemingly, we didn’t say kiddush earlier, because otherwise we wouldn’t have to say kiddush at midnight. If so, the question is why. The only reason given in the MB is because of the safek of leishev, and he doesn’t differentiate between bread and kiddush.

Comment: So it makes sense IMO to assume that the reason is the same by both kiddush and bread, and the reason is the safek of leishev. If there is a safek of leishev, we can’t say it earlier, with or without a b’racha: with: may be levatalah, without: we may need to say the b’racha, so it is better to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it depends on how you look at the patur of rain in general and the mitzvah of eating on the first night. See reshimot shiurim by rav Soloveitchik in the second perek where he talks about the mitzvah. דף כה:ישיבה בסוכה :ב

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Ethan and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. It would be better to give more of the reasoning in the answer rather than send people to a safer they might not have access to. Great to have you learn with us!